# Not able to load more than one JSON using three.js

Tags: json, three.js, blender

I am using the following loadmodel function to load a json into html. (jsons were exported from Blender)

```
(function init(){

    console.log("Init")
    loadmodel('object1');
    loadmodel('object2');
    loadmodel('object3');
    loadmodel('object4');

    requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
})();

function loadmodel(str){


    var json = "{% static 'three/' %}" + str + '.json.gz';
    var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    loader.load(json, function(geometry, materials){

            alfaromeo = new THREE.Mesh(
            geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials)
        );
    alfaromeo.name = str;
    names.push(str);
    scene.add(alfaromeo);
    });
}
```

My problem is that I have more than one json to load and when I call this function for each json, only the first one is getting loaded and the others are not. The same code is working well in my friends computer - all the jsons are loading well.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Actually changing the order worked. Placing object1 at the bottom worked. But still would like to know why  it doesn't work when object1 is at the top

Comment: i dont see any render cycle, are you continuously rendering the scene? it could be the objects did not load in time for the single render and reversing the order gave more time for the object 4 or something...

Comment: I am not rendering continuously. I am rendering only once.

Comment: the load of JSONLoader is asynchronous, you have to render after the load is done....

Answer (score 0):

As one of the comments stands, the JSONLoader is asynchronous, so the best way to be sure you are rendering what has been already downloaded is to trigger the render once you have download the JSON file in your [onLoad method](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Loaders/JSONLoader).

Actually what I would recommend is that you call just once to loadmodel to load just one JSON file, after the first download trigger again a new download, the last of your JSON file download should then trigger the scene render.

```
(function init(){

console.log("Init")
loadmodel('object1');
//this should be called when your last object has been added to the scene
//requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
})();
```

Just a quick n dirty example from your code:

```
function loadmodel(str)
{
     var json = "{% static 'three/' %}" + str + '.json.gz';
     var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
     loader.load(json, function(geometry, materials){

        alfaromeo = new THREE.Mesh(
        geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));

        alfaromeo.name = str;
        names.push(str);
        scene.add(alfaromeo);

        // Add here proper logic to load next model...
        if(str=="object1")
            loadmodel("object2");
        else if()...
        else
        { 
            console.info("done with all downloads!"); 
            requestAnimationFrame(rotate);
        }

    });
}
```